# How do I force Flutter/Dart to require types?

Tags: flutter, dart, typechecking

I'm used to relying on the compiler to catch incompatible type mistakes. By default, Dart offers this only if I remember to specify types. If I forget to include types in the code, then I don't get the type checks.

How do I get the Flutter/Dart compilers to error on the indicated lines in the following code? This code compiles just fine despite being full of type errors.

```dart
class Foo {
  String foo() {
    return "foo";
  }
}

class Bar {
  String bar() {
    return "bar";
  }
}

f() { // would like a missing return type error here (e.g. void)
  print("returns nothing");
}

void g(x) { // would like a missing parameter type error here...
  print(x.bar); // ...so this isn't a missing property at runtime
}

void h() {
  String a = f(); // would like this to error...
  print("$a");  // ...instead of this printing "null"
  g(Foo()); // would like this to error for incorrect parameter type
}
```

If there is a way to do this, how do I do it in Visual Studio Code and Intellij/Android Studio, as well as in dart2js?

Comment: @FernandoRocha: "Why don't you specify types? (legit question)" I don't understand. Are you asking why I accidentally leave out types? I want the compiler to catch my mistakes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `analysis_options.yaml` file to make Dart stricter.

```dart
analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
    implicit-dynamic: false
```

Put this file in the root of your project.

This will disable the situations where Dart fallback with `dynamic` and make it a compile error.

It also disable implicit upcasts like followed:

```dart
Object a = 42;
String b = a; // unless `implicit-cast` is disabled, this is valid
```

Comment: Awesome. But it's not working for me in VS Code. I threw that into pubspec.yaml, did a get packages, rebuilt and reran, and no where did anything ever complain.

Comment: As I said, it's not inside the `pubspec.yaml` but a different file: `analysis_options.yaml`

Comment: Excellent. That did it. Thank you so much! Sorry for reading too fast.

Comment: Remi, do you have these options turned on? Is it good programming practice to choose the stricter style?

Comment: great! But how to ignore this rule for some lines?

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to call Dart Analyzer:

https://dart.dev/tools/dartanalyzer

Example file:

```
main() {
   print('May');
}
```

Result:

```
PS C:\> dartanalyzer.bat --no-implicit-dynamic a.dart
Analyzing a.dart...
  error - Missing return type for 'main'. - a.dart:1:1 - implicit_dynamic_return
```